# Convert Google Maps KML to preferred format on a Hyundai Ioniq EV's BlueLink Map

Tags: google-maps, kml, navigation

I want to upload data for all Eduroam WiFi locations in Canada to my car navigation system which has an "Import Address Book from USB device" option.

I downloaded the current locations I have on my car and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml>
    <Folder>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Eduroam</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-123.143989,49.179125</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Edroam2</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-123.152900,49.155589</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Home</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-123.130431,49.191978</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</kml>
```

So I think it wants latitude and longitude.
Where as the custom Google map provided by Eduroam Canada looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>EduroamCanada</name>
    <description/>
    <Style id="icon-22-normal">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1.1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/22-blue-dot.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x="16" xunits="pixels" y="32" yunits="insetPixels"/>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="icon-22-highlight">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1.1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/22-blue-dot.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x="16" xunits="pixels" y="32" yunits="insetPixels"/>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>1.1</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="icon-22">
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#icon-22-normal</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#icon-22-highlight</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="icon-22-nodesc-normal">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1.1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/22-blue-dot.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x="16" xunits="pixels" y="32" yunits="insetPixels"/>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
...
```

You can find the eduroam Canada custom  map here: https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1mgS5P6gcv0A_5-QuKUb3pNg9VX8&ll=49.1560847597644%2C-123.14908251417819&z=13

How can I convert the Google Map format to what Bluelink wants?
Right now it just says "No supported files" when I stick the USB in.

Comment: Either GPX (Garmin) or KML (Google Earth) will work (USB Stick needs to be formatted correctly in FAT32) not well documented but someone created a pdf https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qfOYbIe_JBIxw01dm_ei5GyBoCU862W_/view

Comment: If you keep scrolling down in the custom Google map KML provided by Eduroam, you'll see the lon, lat coordinates